# NullPointerException for Service-in-Service Injection during test-app

Tags: grails, groovy

Recently came across with a weird scenario, that dependency injection for a service within a service, threw NPE while running *test-app*

Reason for service-in-service injection is to make the GORM/criteriaBuilder as DRY as possible. So following are my two services.

Following class *SearchService1.groovy* is implemented to provide search capability.

```
class SearchService1{
def search = { ...//Calls to local closures to build a dynamic criteria }
...
}
```

Class *SearchService2.groovy* uses the *search* closure of *SearchService1* class

```
class SearchService2{
     def searchService1
     ...
     def searchEntity(){
        searchService1.search()
      }
   }
```

Now, the above stated code works pretty well in *run-app* mode.
But for Integration test written for SearchService2 throws NPE as follows :

```
Cannot invoke method searchEntity() on null object
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method search() on null object
at com.myapp.service.SearchService2.searchEntity(SearchService2.groovy:326)
at com.myapp.service.SearchService2$searchEntity$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at com.myapp.service.SearchService2.searchEntity(SearchService2.groovy:295)
at com.myapp.service.SearchService2$searchEntity.call(Unknown Source)
at com.myapp.integration.SearchService2Tests.testWhenSearch(SearchService2Tests.groovy:125)
```

Am I missing something very basic here ? Any thoughts are greatly appreciated. Many Thnx :)

Snippet from TestClass :

```
class SearchService2Tests extends GroovyTestCase{
 ...
 def searchService2
 ...
 void testWhenSearch(){
    def resultSet = searchService2.searchEntity() //This is the line throwing NPE
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your test class?  Which version of Grails are you using?

Comment: Hello Tim, version of grails is 1.3.7, Updated the question with TestClass snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woah ! Got rid of this stupid error by this workaround.

To TestClass, inject the searchService1 to searchService2 object like this :

```
def searchService2
def searchService2.searchService1 = new SearchService1()
```

But come on ! Is this the right way to do it ? Can anyone explain the above error by the way, that why a Service-in-Service is not instantiated while running test-app.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
class SearchService2Tests extends GroovyTestCase {
    ...
    def searchService1
    def searchService2
    ...
    void testWhenSearch(){
        def resultSet = searchService2.searchEntity()
        ...
    }
}
```

but use  standard Grails service naming convention and placement